# Swapping words across the preposition "as"

Tags: sentence-construction

Can we say the following sentence

> > I have **many foreigners *as* my classmates**.

in the following form:

> > I have **my classmates *as* many foreigners**.

I have seen many people speaking the last-mentioned sentence.

I tried to check the matching meaning of "as" in the above context with the meaning given in [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/as). I think the following meaning matches this context.

> > PREPOSITION Used to refer to the function or character that someone or something has.

Can we swap other combinations in a similar way?

Comment: No you can't. *as* in your example is not a conjunction, which would be needed to do your swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second sentence doesn't make any sense, because the idiom you are using (have many X as Y) is only used when Y is something in a relationship with the subject: relatives, friends, classmates, possessions, employees, homes. "Many foriegners" is not something in any particular relationship with anybody.

Comment: Yes, I think this a common mistake in speaking because the speaker just starts speaking about something related to a context. But at the time of speaking, he figures out that he has actually missed a part which was required grammatically. So they just link the two words as "I have my classmates ... many foreigners." which appears to a listener as "I have my classmates as many foreigners."